# How to evaluate a variable within a dict in jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I would like to evaluate a variable within a dict object in Jinja. Is that possible?

```
{%- set obj_list = ['obj1', 'obj2'] %}
{%- set long_dict_set ={"key":"text text {{ obj_list }} text text"} %}

{{ long_dict_set }}

--Returns
>> {'key': 'text text {{ obj_list }} text text'}
```

In the example, `{{ obj_list }}` is treated as text. Is there a syntax to evaluate this variable within?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `~` to include variables within strings:

`{%- set long_dict_set = {"key":"text text " ~ obj_list ~ " text text"} %}`

Output:

`{'key': "text text ['obj1', 'obj2'] text text"}`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is it possible to remove the square brackets? `[`